# What is the best way to represent a big set of data in a visual way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

The data I have for example is the following DataFrame, it have 3 columns: 'camion'(truck number), 'años' (years), 'media litros' (average liters) and 193 rows. The 'camion' and 'años' columns have not got unique values. Trucks goes from 1 to 7023, steping randomly, and years include years from 2017 to 2020 but not all necessarily.

The code from where I'm getting the dataframe is this:

```py
    valores = new[['camion','litros','año']].groupby(['camion','año']) 
    ['litros'].mean().reset_index(name = 'media litros')
    print(valores)
```

I know how to plot data, but not how to plot such a big data in a way that have sense for the client.

An image of the dataframe I've got:

[image: data frame I have]

I don't know if it could be usefull, here comes a minimum reproducible example of a dataframe like this:

```py
   import pandas as pd
   truck_id = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,12,15,15,15,15,18]
   years = [2018,2020,2017,2017,2019,2018,2020,2018,2017,2019,2018,2020,2018,2020,2017,2018,2019,2020,2017,2020]
   mean = [17138.77, 13282.85, 6088.51, 15550.93, 10253.13, 19841.98, 6936.13, 7763.45, 17856.75, 12498.89, 10671.49, 10049.78, 15805.94, 10918.88, 7069.18, 5865.46, 7385.18, 9759.91, 19019.89, 9599.6]
   df = pd.DataFrame({'camion': truck_id,'year':years,'media':mean})
```

The data is a little poor but I think you could imagine the structure of the data.

Comment: As you have data, check here https://matplotlib.org/ then decide which type of plot fit to your data

Comment: The `pandas` docs provide a [guide on visualising data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) from DataFrames. This uses `matplotlib` and is a good starting point.

Comment: You can first groupby you data as you have done then you can call dataframe.plot.bar() and this will plot a bar graph with you data.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The problem is that I dont know wat is the bes way to do it. There are 193 groups, so if I make 193 groups of 4 elements the plot will be useless. Any idea of how could I show the information?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution:-

```
import pandas as pd

# sample dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'camion': [1, 1,2, 2],
'Date': [2020., 2011, 2005, 2006],
'Media Litros':[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
})
```

```
Date.  camios  Media Litros

2020.0  1      1000
2011.0  1      2000
2005.0  2      3000
2006.0  2      4000
```

```
df.groupby('camion'['MediaLitros'].plot(legend=True))
```

[image: Visulization of result]